# Можно ли получить доступ к директиве внутри компонента, на который повесили директиву?

Tags: angular, angular8

У меня есть следующий код:

```
<my-extremely-brilliant-component myDirective></my-extremely-brilliant-component>
```

Можно ли внутри компонента MyExtremelyBrilliantComponent получить доступ к директиве myDirective?

Answer (score 1):

https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection#directive-and-component

> Components and directives on the same element share an injector.

Поэтому любую директиву можно получить из инжектора компонента посредством DI:

```
class MyExtremelyBrilliantComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(MyDirective) @Self() @Optional() myDirective: MyDirective | null) {
    if (myDirective !== null) {
      // Директива была привязана к компоненту...
    }
  }
}
```

`@Optional()` - это флаг, который говорит инжектору не кидать эксепшн `No provider for MyDirective` в случаях, когда директива не была привязана к компоненту.